# Read image from URL save it in isolated storage and read and binding to a image source

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, url, binding, isolatedstorage

I'm saving an image from URL link to isolated storage and later I need to binding it to an image.

This is the code where I get and save the image:
(the path value and the value is a class attribute)

```
private void saveImage(string name)
{
        path = name;

        string uri = "http://sherutnetphpapi.cloudapp.net/mini_logos/" + path;
        WebClient m_webClient = new WebClient();
        imageUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);
        m_webClient.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted);
        m_webClient.OpenReadAsync(imageUri);
}

void webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsf = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsf.FileExists(path))
            {
                myIsf.DeleteFile(path);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsf.CreateFile(path);

            StreamResourceInfo sri = null;
            sri = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);

            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(sri.Stream);
            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);

            // Encode WriteableBitmap object to a JPEG stream.
            System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(wb, fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
}
```

In another class I read the image and binding it to an image source:

```
public class CompanyItem
{
    public String companyIcon { get; set; } //save the file name in the isolated storge
    public String companyName { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public BitmapImage ReadImageFromStorage 
    {
        get
        {
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            string isoFileName = this.companyIcon;
            var stream = isoStore.OpenFile(isoFileName, System.IO.FileMode.Open);
            image.SetSource(stream);
            return image;
        }
    }
```

The xaml code is:

```
<Image Height="63" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="392,7,0,0" Name="imgConpamyIcon" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="70" CacheMode="BitmapCache" Source="{Binding ReadImageFromStorage}" />
```

The image is in a listBox within a listBox

Please help me .... It drives me crazy

Comment: What is your problem in this?? where it is going wrong?

Comment: When I run the program i get Exception: "the Value does not fall within the expected range" In the class CompanyItem  in the line image.SetSource(stream);

Comment: when the program try to get and save the image i get the message: "A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI.

Comment: Here is a quick suggestion `if (isoStore.FileExists(filePath))
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = isoStore.OpenFile(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    image.SetSource(reader.ReadLine());
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: I think the problem is at the function "webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted" when we use the  
sri = Application.GetResourceStream(imageUri);  the imageUri is not the value that GetResourceStream should get

Comment: Look at my code. It is working solution.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916905/image-loaded-from-isolated-storage-are-not-binding-at-all

Answer (score 1):

After thoroughly ovserving your code, I got few things:

In your SaveImage class, `imageUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative);`
change it to `UriKind.Absolute`

and then in `webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted` you can directly set the `bitmap.SetSource(e.Result);` instead of using `StreamResourceInfo` class

And again, I dnt know whether it is valid to bind the Source property of Image tag to BitmapImage in XAML(It's valid in code behind)

Comment: I did what you suggested. And it really changed something. the comment: "A relative URI cannot be created because the 'uriString' parameter represents an absolute URI" not appears. but now i get the Exception "WebException Was unhandled - The remot server returned an error: Not Fount" for the line: bitmap.SetSource(e.Result); do you have any suggestion why it's happening?

Comment: I debge it now and the program not even get into the function 'webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted'. In fact what is actually happening I create an object that represents a company. One of its attribute is that icon (company logo). At the start, I read all the data from the network includes a images - the icons. so the function saveImage' run n times for all the companies and only after the function 'webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted' run n times. Do I need to use a wait function???

Comment: In that case, problem occurs mainly with the `path`. Because when some i th instance of webClient_ImageOpenReadCompleted is called then actual path value would have been already changed. Let me see if any alternative is available