# Image loaded from Isolated storage are not binding at all

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-phone-8

I save image from web, load it to BitmapImage and try to bind image control to BitmapImage along with some text chunks. Problem is pictures are not displayed even if I invoke NotifyPropertyChanged. I might miss something.

Here is my code:

```
public class MovieData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public bool Today { get; set; }
    public string DetailsUrl { get; set;  }
    public string Title { get; set;  }
    public string Country { get; set;  }
    public string Year { get; set; }
    public string Director { get; set;  }
    public string Genre { get; set; } 
    public string Duration { get; set; } 
    public string Restriction { get; set; } 
    public string Description { get; set; } 
    public string Poster { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage PosterLocal;
    public string LargePoster { get; set; }
    public BitmapImage LargePosterLocal { get; set; }
    public DateTime AirDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastDate { get; set; } 
    public string Cinema { get; set; } 
    public string IsDetailsLoaded { get; set; }
    public HttpResponseMessage HtmlRequest { get; set; }
    private static CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    public bool IsTaskCanceled = false;

    public async Task<bool> GetDetailsAsync()
    {
        if (this.Year == null)
        {

            this.IsDetailsLoaded = "visible";
            NotifyPropertyChanged("IsDetailsLoaded");
            Uri uri = new Uri(this.DetailsUrl);
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            HtmlNode htmlNode = new HtmlNode(0, htmlDocument, 1);
            MovieData Item = new MovieData();
            string HtmlResult;

            try
            {
                HtmlRequest = await client.GetAsync(uri, _cts.Token);
                HtmlResult = await HtmlRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
                HtmlResult = null;
                this.IsDetailsLoaded = "Collapsed";
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsDetailsLoaded");
            }
            catch (System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
                HtmlResult = null;
                this.IsDetailsLoaded = "Collapsed";
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsDetailsLoaded");
            }

            if (!(HtmlResult == null) && HtmlRequest.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                await this.DownloadPosterAsync();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("PosterLocal");
                htmlDocument.LoadHtml(HtmlResult);
                this.LargePoster = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='cinema_img']/a").GetAttributeValue("href", "No poster image");
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LargePoster");
                await this.DownloadLargePosterAsync();
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LargePosterLocal");
                htmlNode = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='cinema_desc']");
                this.Title = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("h1"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
                this.Country = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[2]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Country");
                this.Year = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[3]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Year");
                this.Director = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[4]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Director");
                this.Genre = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[6]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Genre");
                this.Duration = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[7]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Duration");
                this.Restriction = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[8]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Restriction");
                this.Description = GetStringFromNode(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[9]/p"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
                this.AirDate = GetAirDate(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[1]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AirDate");
                this.LastDate = GetLastDate(htmlNode.SelectSingleNode("p[1]"));
                NotifyPropertyChanged("LastDate");
                this.IsDetailsLoaded = "Collapsed";
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsDetailsLoaded");

            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    #region public async Task<bool> DownloadPosterAsync() //Method for download images from web and save them to isolated storage with same name.
    public async Task<bool> DownloadPosterAsync()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient(); //Instantiate WebClient

        var isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        string DestFileName = "small\\"+Path.GetFileName(this.Poster);
        if (!isoStore.FileExists(DestFileName))
        {
            client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(this.Poster));

            client.OpenReadCompleted += (s, e) => //Wait for completion
            {


                if (!isoStore.DirectoryExists("small"))
                {
                    isoStore.CreateDirectory("small");
                }
                var tempBitmap = new BitmapImage(); //Create temp bitmap container
                tempBitmap.SetSource(e.Result); //Copy stream to bitmap container
                var writeableBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(tempBitmap); //Create WriteableBitmap out of temp bitmap
                using (var isoFileStream = isoStore.CreateFile(DestFileName)) //Create file in Isolated Storage
                {
                    var width = writeableBitmap.PixelWidth; //Set attributes
                    var height = writeableBitmap.PixelHeight; // Set some more
                    Extensions.SaveJpeg(writeableBitmap, isoFileStream, width, height, 0, 100); //Finally save .jpeg
                }

            };
        }
        BitmapImage image = null;
        using (var imageStream = await LoadImageAsync(DestFileName))
        {
            if (imageStream != null)
            {
                image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(imageStream);
            }
        }
        this.PosterLocal = image;
        return true;
    }
    #endregion
```

And XAML chunk:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="MoviesDataTemplate">
        <Grid Margin="12,7,0,5">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{Binding PosterLocal}" Width="99" Height="136" Grid.Column="0" Stretch="UniformToFill" CacheMode="BitmapCache"/>
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextAccentStyle}">
                    <Run Text="{Binding AirDate, StringFormat=MMMM dd\, yyyy}" ></Run>
                </TextBlock> 
                <!--<TextBlock Text="{Binding AirTimes}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="12,0,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>-->
                <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" Visibility="{Binding IsDetailsLoaded}" Margin="0,12"></ProgressBar>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

I search through SO and found lots of topics but didn't find resolution. I guess my problem is that image loading after Datacontext assigning, and NotifyPropertyChanged does not work for bitmap images because every over property assigns at the same time and shows in control. Also I checked that images actually downloaded, stored at Isolated Storage and was loaded . (Hard coded image to property and it worked). Any suggestions how to make binding work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should [Bind to properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc278072%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and in the code you provided - `PosterLocal` is not a property. In this case you can try to use such a getter of your `PosterLocal`:

```
public BitmapImage PosterLocal
{
   get
   {
       BitmapImage temp = new BitmapImage();

       using (IsolatedStorageFile ISF = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
       using (IsolatedStorageFileStream file = ISF.OpenFile(posterLocal, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            temp.SetSource(file);
       return temp;
    }
}

private string posterLocal; // this in case you probably will need to save somewhere the file name
```

If you need your `PosterLocal` only for binding (one-way) then getter should be sufficient. And the filename you change with `string posterLocal`.

In this case you no longer need a part of your code in `DownloadPosterAsync` - getter will be activated with PropertyChanged. Just after saving file to IS do:

```
posterLocal = DestFileName;
```

Comment: Dammit! I see now. I added {get; set;} and it worked like a charm!!! THat small mistake caused me a lost day! But anyways I will try your approach as it looks more elegant.

Comment: @RovshanMamedov Consider also (as using IsolatedStorage asynchronously) arming this with Mutex/Monitor/Lock if you see that same file could be accessed from more than one source. Personaly - I also like such small mistakes (that takes plenty of your time) the most ;)

Answer (score 0):

you may try:

```
using(var targetFile=System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()
.OpenFile("fileName", FileMode.Open))
{
    PosterLocal = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(targetFile, 100, 100);
}
```

Comment: 'PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(targetFile, 100, 100);' returns WritableBitmap. Is it good to use WritebleBitmap just for binding and showing it?